# adding functionality to daviferreira's WYSIWYG medium editor

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wysiwyg, medium-editor

I am making a plug in to make his medium editor more like medium.  I am not sure how to turn off the user's ability to press enter if they have not typed anything or how to add a line dividing paragraphs if the user presses enter twice.

Answer (score 1):

medium-editor supports a `disableDoubleReturn` option which you can pass into the editor during instantiation.  This prevents the user from being able to have 2 or more consecutive new lines.  I believe this would accomplish the first requirement you listed.

```
var mediumEditor = new MediumEditor('.editor', { disableDoubleReturn: true });
```

To accomplish the 2nd requirement you listed, you could add some functionality into medium-editor itself to call a callback when the user hits return or even add a `hrBetweenParagraphs` option which could add a line in between consecutive paragraphs.

You could implement either of these in the `bindReturn` method of `core.js` in the most recent version of the repo, as this is where hitting enter is handled.  We accept many pull requests very frequently, so we'd be happy to take in something like this :)

[medium-editor repo on github](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor)

Answer (score 0):

For code ideas, take a look at grande.js which implements both of these subtle features:

https://github.com/mduvall/grande.js/

Particularly: `function preprocessKeyDown()` and `function insertHorizontalRule()`

Answer (score 0):

since u r using the davi's editor..
u can add your code to **bindParagraphCreation**
for enter press where **keyevent.which == 13**, check for

- textContent

  inside the node.. and if its' empty.. stop the event with preventdefault() and return ..
  second thing u can do the same way only :)